# How do I find out , what exception occurred in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, tcp, exception, spring-integration

How do I find out , what exception occurred in spring integration, when I send a message to a server via TCP client. So , there is an `<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory>` ( client ! ), and it has an error channel. When a connection created between client and server and after few seconds the server closes the connection there is an exception.It's OK, and I able to catch it, the exception is : "Read timed out". But when the connection dosn't create , because the server doesn't listen the specified port, I don't cache any exception via error channel.
Therefore, I'am trying to cache exceptions in that way :

```
try{
  success = gateway.send(adaptor);
  } catch ( MessagingException exc){
    System.out.println("Exception occurred : Timed out waiting for response");
}
```

But - at this point - I cache

> Timed out waiting for response

exception for any reason. ( for example, when the server close the connection, or the the connection doesn't occurre ) A can't take difference between exceptions. Therefore , I listen both this catching mechanism and the error channel at once.

**My not elegant solution is :**

```
Main service class :
success = 0;
try{
  success = gateway.send(adaptor); // this will be return 1, if there aren't any exception
return "Success";
} catch ( MessagingException exc){
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // I have to wait for the error channel's message, this portion not elegant !
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    return "ERROR";
}
if ( success == 2){
  return "The server closed the connection";
} else {                
  return "There is no connection with server";
}
```

The error handler snippet is :

```
public void onException(TcpConnectionExceptionEvent event){
  mainService.setSuccess(2);
}
```

Is there any simple, and more elegant solution ?

**Correction:**
I use Spring integration 4.04 and here are my client pipe's beans :

```
<!-- Client side -->

    <int:gateway id="gw"
        service-interface="hu.gmxdev.climaxreplica.service.SimpleGateway"
        default-request-channel="outputchannel" />

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
        type="client" host="localhost" port="10001" single-use="true"
        so-timeout="5000"
        />

    <int:channel id="outputchannel" />

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
        request-channel="outputchannel" reply-channel="replychannel"
        connection-factory="client" request-timeout="5000" reply-timeout="5000" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="replychannel"
        method="reply" ref="echoService" id="serviceactivator">
    </int:service-activator>
    <int:channel id="replychannel"></int:channel>

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter id="event"
        event-types="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionExceptionEvent"
        channel="errorChannel" />
    <int:channel id="errorChannel"></int:channel>

    <int:service-activator ref="tcpErrorHandler" method="onException"
        input-channel="errorChannel">
    </int:service-activator>
```

**I add a track trace.
*This one is, when the server closes an established connection, or the server doesn't answer to the client within the expected time. The track trace are same in both case. :***

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:223)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:75)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:103)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:241)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:304)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:295)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.send(Unknown Source)
    at hu.gmxdev.climaxreplica.service.MainService.senddata(MainService.java:88)
    at hu.gmxdev.climaxreplica.controller.MainController.senddata(MainController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: The "connection factory" does not have an `error-channel`. Please show your integration flow configuration and tell us what version of Spring Integration you are using.

Comment: Hi Gary ! You have right ! I have supplemented my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MessagingException` is thrown under both circumstances...

```
11:58:08.068 ERROR [main][org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway] Tcp Gateway exception
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response
```

and

```
12:00:34.859 WARN  [main][org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway] failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to send or receive
```

You won't get a `TcpConnectionExceptionEvent` in the second case - that event is for exceptions on a **specific established** connection. Since we didn't actually establish a connection, there's no connection to report an exception for.

In order to determine the actual exception, you should traverse the `cause` tree; something like:

```
if (e.getCause() != null) {
    if (e.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConnectException) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also change your gateway to throw a `ConnectException`...

```
int send(Foo adapter) throws ConnectException;
```

...and the framework will automatically unwrap it for you...

```
try {
    success = gateway.send(adaptor);
}
catch (MessagingException exc) {
    System.out.println("Exception occurred : " + exc.getMessage());
}
catch (ConnectException e) {
    ...
}
```

The messaging exception for a timeout (no response) is a `MessageTimeoutException` (subclass of `MessagingException`). For errors that occur while waiting for a reply, you should get...

```
throw new MessagingException("Exception while awaiting reply", (Throwable) reply.getPayload());
```

Comment: I have tired your suggestions, I added the 'throws ConnectionException' to the send method, and catch(ConnectionException e ) to my main method. Now, there are that situations : When there is no established connection I can catch ConnectException, it is good. When the server closes the established connection I cache MessagingException with e.getCause() equal null. And when the server establishes a connection, but doesn't answer the client I also catch MessagingException and e.getCause() equal null. Therefore I can't take difference between two exceptions.

Comment: In the case of the timeout it's a subclass of the MessagingException (MessageTimeoutException) so it won't have a cause. For the other case, please print a stack trace and add it to your question.

Comment: I added additional info to the answer.

Comment: I placed track trace to my question. Other hand , I don't really understand your last comment. Where do I have to place the throw ?

Comment: It seems to be a problem in spring integration tcp client pipe. I have succeed cache different exceptions, but the integration has strange behaviour. When the server closes the connection at the first time I catch Socket close exception, but after when server closes connection again I get Read timed out exception again and again. Is it possible ?

Comment: My comment about the throw is that the tcp gateway throws that exception when a socket error is detected while we are waiting for a reply. If you are getting a timeout when the server closes the socket, it implies the network has not propagated the socket close to the client. If you turn on DEBUG logging you should get some indication. If there are no error logs then it implies the client was not informed of the socket closing.